# Get record number of total items in ticket paginator

Tags: python, django, templates

i have applied paginator on my query objects. when i get records greater then 15, they are skpped to the 2 pages.

that words fine for me. but i want to ask what if i want to know my record number in the template?

example: if i get 22 records, i want to get record number 1,2,3,4, .... 22

here is my code:

```
paginator.Paginator(query_results, 15)
page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
tickets = ticket_paginator.page(page)
```

my template code:

```
<th>{% trans "Title" %}</th>
{% for item in items.object_list %}
<th><a href='view/{{ item.id }}'>{{ item.title }}</a></th>
```

here i wanto to get the record number.

```
<th> #</th>
<th>{% trans "Title" %}</th>
 {% for item in items.object_list %}
 <th>counter</th>
 <th><a href='view/{{ item.id }}'>{{ item.title }}</a></th>
```

Do anyone knows about it?
help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to re-phrase your question as at least I am not really sure what you are actually asking. My guess is though that you want to use [`page_range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator.page_range).

```
paginator = Paginator(objects, 15)
pr = paginator.page_range
```

In your template you can something like

```
{% for page_num in prange %}
    {% if objects.number  == page_num %}
        {{page_num}} // current page
    {% else %}
        <a href="?page={{page_num}}">{{ page_num }}</a> //next page
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```